# Alphabatize all images pulled from a resx file C#

Tags: c#, resx, alphabetical

I have a drop down combo box that changes the image of a picture box. The images are stored in a resx file with an array that counts them, so that if I ever decide to add more, I need only to update the combo box, and add the images to the resx file. The problem I'm having is that when I update the image with the combo box, the images in the resx aren't in alphabetical order, but they do change the image on the picture box.

Here is my code

```
        ResourceSet cardResourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

        attributes = new Image[cardCount];
        cardCount = 0;

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in cardResourceSet)
        {
            string resourceKey = (string)entry.Key;
            object resource = entry.Value;

            cardCount++;
        }

        attributes = new Image[cardCount];
        cardCount = 0;

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in cardResourceSet)
        {
            attributes[cardCount] = (Image)entry.Value;
            cardCount++;
        }

        if (attributeBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            this.cardImage.Image = attributes[attributeBox.SelectedIndex];
        }
```

How can I go about making it sort the resources in the resx alphabetically?

Comment: Do you want to sort by `Key` or `Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of [`GetResourceSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset(v=vs.110).aspx), [`ResourceSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset(v=vs.110).aspx), implements `IEnumerable`, so you should be able to run some LINQ ordering on it:

```
foreach (var entry in cardResourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(de => de.Key))
{

}
```

Since you're iterating over it twice (though I'm not really sure of the point of the first for-loop, unless there's other code),  you may want to assign the sorted results to a separate variable:

```
var sortedCardResourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(de => de.Key).ToList();

foreach (var entry in sortedCardResourceSet)
{
    ...
}

...
```

Comment: With a little bit of time, I was able to get this working. Thanks!